# How can I send transaction in eth2.0

Tags: transactions, eth-2.0

I want to use BLS signature scheme to sign and publish a transaction on a testnet. As far as I know, sepolia is running as PoS now and I guess it uses BLS but I couldn't find any tutorial that uses BLS to sign transactions in js. Could you refer me a resource about it?

Answer (score 1):

To ones who are trying to use BLS in transactions, I got an answer from the Eth devs: BLS signature is only used by the validators to sign their messages in the consensus layer, they are not used in the execution layer.
the transactions in the execution layer uses ECDSA signatures with the secp256k1.